# mathtools.sty not found in kile

Tags: kile

How could I solve this following problem:

```
 'mathtools.sty' not found .\usepackage
```

I am using following packages:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{report} 
 \usepackage{textcomp, amssymb} 
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage[all]{xy}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
 \usepackage{helvet} 
 \usepackage{color}
```

I am compiling my `.tex` code in kile.

Comment: Which TeX distribution do you use?

Comment: i do not understand what do you mean. what is **tlmgr**.There is ubuntu in my machine. how would install it there?

Comment: I will delete my comment, it will not help, please answer Mico's question. :)

Comment: @ mico, i am not so aware about the distribution of latex too. i have ubuntu machine. i use kile for compiling .

Comment: @thetna: If you type `tex` at a command prompt, you'll get a message string (e.g., `This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2012)`), and then a `**` prompt. (Type "control-d" to exit from TeX's interactive mode.) Or, if you type `latex` at a command prompt, you might something like `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)`, followed by a `**` interactive prompt. Your system's TeX distribution is the part of the message string inside parentheses (in my case, "TeX Live 2012").

Comment: @Mico, I googled and now i installed tex live. Could you please give me direction, what should i do to get rid of my problem ?

Comment: If TeXLive is installed properly, you shouldn't be experiencing a "package not found" error of the variety you describe. That's why I was asking which TeX distribution you use. Is it TeXLive 2012, or an older version? Please advise.

Comment: This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2009/Debian).

Comment: Any chance at all that you can download and install TeXLive 2012? See the site http://www.tug.org/texlive/ for instructions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5965/discussion-between-thetna-and-mico)

Answer (score 13):

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex3
```

solved my problem.The reason behind this problem was, latex mathematical style file mathtools.sty was missing. When i installed `texlive-latex3` those 
missing files were added. This is lighter than the full texlive.

Comment: This is very short for an answer. Can you more specific why this command resolves your problem. Perhaps a summary of the content of the chat?